# Table td, different div heights vertical align top

Tags: html, html-table, height, valign

I am currently working on a newsletter that has 2 columns but the first div height does not adjust when the other one has multiple lines. I want them to be vertically aligned top or auto adjust height depending on the content without changing the image and Read more button height. Everything has to be in line. (Both images aligned, Read more at the div's bottom, etc.)

Here's the code :

```html
<tr>
  <td>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="650" class="contenttable" align="center">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td style="font-size:0;">
            <div class="listing_text fullwidthsm" style="display:inline-block;padding-top:5%;padding-bottom:5%;padding-right:5%;padding-left:5%;width:40%;height: 100%;">
              <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" align="center">
                <tbody>
                  <tr height="38">
                    <td valign="top" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;color:#68C04A;font-size:16px;">
                      <a href="#" title="The Musical Circus Duo. Tuesday August 18 at 7 p.m." style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:16px;line-height:1.5;color:#68C04A;text-decoration:none;text-align:right;width:100%;display:block;font-weight:bold;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;">
                      The Musical Circus Duo. Tuesday August 18 at 7 p.m.
                      </a>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td style="font-size:10px;line-height:1;">&nbsp;</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <a href="#" title="The Musical Circus Duo. Tuesday August 18 at 7 p.m." style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:16px;line-height:1.5;color:#68C04A;text-decoration:none;text-align:right;width:100%;display:block;font-weight:bold;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;">
                      <img src="https://img.url" width="100%">
                      </a>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td style="font-size:10px;line-height:1;">&nbsp;</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="listing_text" align="right">
                      <a href="#" title="The Musical Circus Duo. Tuesday August 18 at 7 p.m." style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:16px;line-height:1.5;color:#68C04A;text-decoration:none;text-align:right;width:100%;display:block;font-weight:bold;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;">Read more &gt;</a>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
            <div class="listing_text fullwidthsm" style="display:inline-block;padding-top:5%;padding-bottom:5%;padding-right:5%;padding-left:5%;width:40%;">
              <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" align="center">
                <tbody>
                  <tr height="38">
                    <td valign="top" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;color:#68C04A;font-size:16px;">
                      <a href="#" title="Special Meeting Of The Council On Tuesday, August 11, At 7:00 P.M." style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:16px;line-height:1.5;color:#68C04A;text-decoration:none;text-align:right;width:100%;display:block;font-weight:bold;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;">
                      Special Meeting Of The Council On Tuesday, August 11, At 7:00 P.M.
                      </a>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td style="font-size:10px;line-height:1;">&nbsp;</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <a href="#" title="Special Meeting Of The Council On Tuesday, August 11, At 7:00 P.M." style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:16px;line-height:1.5;color:#68C04A;text-decoration:none;text-align:right;width:100%;display:block;font-weight:bold;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;">
                      <img src="https://img.url" width="100%">
                      </a>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td style="font-size:10px;line-height:1;">&nbsp;</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="listing_text" align="right">
                      <a href="#" title="Special Meeting Of The Council On Tuesday, August 11, At 7:00 P.M." style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:16px;line-height:1.5;color:#68C04A;text-decoration:none;text-align:right;width:100%;display:block;font-weight:bold;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;">Read more &gt;</a>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </td>
```

[How it looks like right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alD00.png)

Comment: Constructive advice: Tables are for tabular data. Use css grid or flexbox. It will change your life. A small part of it anyway.

Comment: I agree with Rob. CSS Grid of Flexbox is basically what you want here. It's easier to work with and can be responsive to different viewport widths/heights.

Comment: You can use CSS Grid, I agree with @RobMoll. You can use bootstrap 4 card.